Getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223BeanInfoSupport" in Jmeter-5.6.3 when adding "JSR233 PreProcessor"
I am getting error Message "Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessorBeanInfo" when I am trying to add JSR223 PreProcessor.
The latest version (5.6.2 & 5.6.3) has JSR223 PreProcessor functionality broken. Can you please add it to newer version.
Please note that required jar file is present in Lib folder with JMETER 5.6.3 default download "groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar" and it does match with file (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-jsr223/3.0.20/)
I have tried to replace it with latest version "groovy-jsr223-3.0.22jar" from below URL but no success.
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-jsr223/3.0.22/
